# Installing cv2 on linux server

Tags: python, linux, bash, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to opencv i.e cv2 on my Linux server which has following configurations.

> Linux D07-CPT-8gb-4cpu-nyc1 4.4.0-92-generic #115-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug
>   10 09:04:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Before trying on the server I tried this command on my Bash for Windows and working fine here.

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

I ran the same command on Linux server but when I type `import cv2` I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

`opencv`is not listed when I check with pip freeze.
Note: I am using python 3.5.2

Comment: print(sys.version)

Comment: @Silencer I just checked that it getting imported for python2 but not python3

Comment: sudo python3 -m pip install opencv-python

Comment: @Silencer Done. Thanks a ton.Awesome. Please add that as an answer so I can upvote.

Comment: Follow @Silencers method. It's flawless and almost always works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least on Ubuntu 16.04, there exist `Python 2` and `Python 3`.

So when install package for python, you should be care of your python version. The default `python` and `pip` is for `Python 2`.

**Solutions**:

> **1**. specific the Python version

```
sudo python3 -m pip install opencv-python
```

> **2**. install `python3-pip`, and then use `python3` and `pip3`

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install opencv-python
```